# Removing the massive amount of for-loops in this code

Tags: python

Are there ways to avoid this triply nested for-loop?

```
def add_random_fields():
from numpy.random import rand
server = couchdb.Server()
databases = [database for database in server if not database.startswith('_')]
for database in databases:
    for document in couchdb_pager(server[database]):
        if 'results' in server[database][document]:
            for tweet in server[database][document]['results']:
                if tweet and 'rand_num' not in tweet:
                    print document
                    tweet['rand_num'] = rand()
                    server[database].save(tweet)
```

**Update**

People suggesting that I use a generator reminded me that I forgot to mention that `couchdb_pager` is a generator over the list `server[database]`.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're descending through three separate levels of data. Unless you can flatten them or skip one, you have to use a for-loop for each level in the hierarchy. I'd suggest refactoring some of your loops out into their own functions.

Comment: Maybe using a generator or iterator?

Comment: As it is I don't see any problem with this code - it's readable and efficient. If you really don't like the nesting you could do something like `documents = (document for database in databases for document in couchdb_pager(server[database]) if 'results' in document)` then loop through the documents.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tweaks that can improve this code:

```
def add_random_fields():
    from numpy.random import rand
    server = couchdb.Server()
    databases = (server[database] for database in server if not database.startswith('_'))
    # immediately fetch the Server object rather then the key, 
    # changes to a generator to avoid instantiating all the database objects at once
    for database in databases:
        for document in couchdb_pager(database):
            document = database[document] 
            # same here, avoid holding keys when you can have the objects

            for tweet in document.get('results', []):
            # rather then checking for the key, have it return a default that does the same thing
                if tweet and 'rand_num' not in tweet:
                    print document
                    tweet['rand_num'] = rand()
                    database.save(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the question comments - there's no real way to avoid them (unless you can restructure the databases!), but the code can be made more readable by removing the loops into a separate generator function, especially since you're not doing any processing between each loop.

Consider something like (caution: untested):

```
def find_all_document_tweets( server ):
    databases = [database for database in server if not database.startswith('_')]
    for database in databases:
        for document in couchdb_pager(server[database]):
            if 'results' in server[database][document]:
                for tweet in server[database][document]['results']:
                    yield database, document, tweet

def add_random_fields():
    from numpy.random import rand
    server = couchdb.Server()
    for ( database, document, tweet ) in find_all_document_tweets( server ):
        if tweet and 'rand_num' not in tweet:
            print document
            tweet['rand_num'] = rand()
            server[database].save(tweet)
```

As an extra bonus, it seems likely that the loops now in `find_all_document_tweets` will be common in your code, so that it's now usable elsewhere.